# Facebook Graph API: GET for a Group doesn't work for most public groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to query for public groups from the Graph API. It doesn't work for any public group that i'm a part of or not, and it does for a barebones group that I just created as public. I'm wondering if there is some other permissions piece on a public group that may be causing this issue? Or what else it may be that's causing this?

Here's the id for my group that works: 267078727879736

Here's some id's for the groups that don't work: 236852523907926, 2051372101755096

Here's the error I get:

```
"error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '2051372101755096' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "AnM_-NFAUDm5frzToodpF0c"
  }
}
```

Also, by nature of what i'm trying to develop, I need to get information from groups that I'm not a part of. I'm not sure if that's possible.

Right now I'm only using a User Access Token, but could this possibly go away anyway when I get an App Review token?

If somebody else wants to make a barebones group and throw me the ID, I can try it out.

Comment: It is by design.

Comment: So I can only access groups that I’ve created, not even ones that I’m a part of?

Comment: Cuz I can’t even query the groups that I’m a part of.

Comment: What is required in the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/group/feed

Comment: I’m not even trying to get to the feed tho, just do a normal /{group-id} query for the top level group info. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/group

Comment: Anyone ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I’m pretty sure it was changes that Facebook made to the API. After some shit happened with PII a couple years back, FB ramped up the permissions and cracked down on what queries were able to actually return. So, I don’t think this is actually possible, unfortunately.

Comment: No problem, sorry to hear you’re having trouble. Might have to go with a web scraper, depending on your use case?